# Linq sum and null

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sum

I have the query:

```
var qq = (from c in db.tblArcadeGames
        where
            c.IsDeleted == false &&
            c.ParentGameID == 0 &&
            c.Approved == true
        let aggPlays = c.Plays + db.tblArcadeGames.Where(v => v.ParentGameID == c.ID).Sum(v => (int?)v.Plays)
        orderby aggPlays descending
        select new { c, aggPlays })
        .Skip(Skip)
        .Take(Fetch);

foreach (var g in qq)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("{" + g.aggPlays + "}\n");
}
```

When I print out `aggPlays` in the loop above they come out as:

```
{21}
{}
{}
{}
```

The problem seems to be that the `Sum()` returns `null` if no records exist.  I'm not sure how to get around this so that `c.Plays + null` wont equal `null` but just `c.Plays`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can correct this by not returning `int?`, but rather convert to an `int` directly:

```
.Sum(v => v.Plays ?? 0)
```

Comment: Thanks this works!  Why is the sum of an empty set null though in linq to sql?  A sum of an empty set should be 0 right?

Comment: @TomGullen *"`Sum()` always returns 0 for an empty sequence in plain LINQ; it seems that it is rather a LINQ to SQL deficiency, and even then it should be only possible if the values you sum are themselves nullable (because otherwise the return type of Sum would be plain* `decimal` *, not* `decimal?` *)."* From http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/360365/linq-sum-method-return-value

Comment: @robjb none of the columns are nullable, is this a bug in linq to sql then?

Comment: @TomGullen It looks to me like you're telling LINQ you want to `Sum()` a collection of `int?` values, which happens to sometimes be empty. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @robj the `(int?)` in the query is to prevent it throwing errors, all I'm trying to do is sum a collection of non nullable ints.  If no records exist in the query to sum it returns `null` when I think it would be better for it to return `0`.

Comment: @TomGullen If the values are non-nullable, how does casting to `int?` add any safety? It tells the compiler to invoke an overloaded `Sum()` method for nullable ints. The overloaded method accepting a collection of `int?` has an `int?` return type, and I think it makes sense to return null in this case. If the values are all non-nullable, then avoid casting to nullable (which is what this solution does.)

Comment: @robj if I do `int updateGamePlays = db.tblArcadeGames.Where(c => c.ParentGameID == GameID).Sum(c => c.Plays);` it throws `System.InvalidOperationException: The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.` if no values exist in the query.  If I add `?? 0` I get `Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'int'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6217/discussion-between-robjb-and-tom-gullen)

Answer (score 1):

```
    int response =
    (from p in data.tbHoraires
     where p.eid == eid && p.annee == annee && p.obligatoire == true
     select (int?)p.nbminute ?? 0).Sum();
```